# How to use Read()

Tags: cakephp

In a Controller, I got this:

```
 $this->Site1->post_id=$id;
 $this->set('posts', $this->Site1->read());
```

And when I replaced it by this line of code:
     $this->set('posts', $this->Site1->read('post_id', $id));

But the returned result is totally different.

Is there any difference between them?

Is it possible to make this two lines of code neat by re-writing it into one line of code?

```
 $this->Site1->post_id=$id;
 $this->set('posts', $this->Site1->read());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is totally different because you told the `read()` method to fetch only the `post_id` column. That's what happens when you pass a string as the first argument to `read()`. You can also pass an array of columns as the first argument, or `null` to fetch all columns. The second argument is the ID of the record you want to retrieve. See the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1029/read) for examples.

> Is it possible to make this two lines of code neat by re-writing it into one line of code?

If you want to fit it all on one line, try: `$this->set('posts', $this->Site1->read(null, $id);`

Answer (score 1):

As another option, you can also simply use [findBy](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1026/findBy)

```
$this->set('posts', $this->Site1->findByPostId($id));
```